# how to show shadow/border of <ion-navbar> when using <ion-segment> in Ionic 2

Tags: html, css, ionic2, border, shadow

As title, I'm tring to show the shadow/border of  within  but I couldn't find the solution.. I used some css code but nothing change

This is my HTML code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="{{this.appService.appColor}}">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Feedbacks
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar color="{{this.appService.appColorDark}}">
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="seg" color="{{this.appService.appStyle}}">
      <ion-segment-button value="users">
        <font color="white">Users Messages</font>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="visitors">
        <font color="white">Visitor Messages</font>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

HTML Output:

[image]

Needed Output:

[image]

> Note: this picture has been drawn by windows paint. I uploaded to give you sample example for what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think the best solution to solve this problem is replace segment with tabs.